# 2 version PHPon the same xampp

Tags: php, xampp

I need to run 2 php versions on the same xampp.
v 5.6.4 (original)
v 7.4.0 (sub version)
Most of my projects use php v 5.6.4.
I downloaded it from https://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/

version [ 12/17/2019 11:16 PM 25960852 ] php-7.4.1-nts-Win32-vc15-x64.zip.

I have configured the environment successfully.
However, I cannot run xampp.
I'm not very familiar with this area, please help me.

Thank you for your attention to this issue

```
File httpd-xampp.conf
#
# XAMPP settings
#

<IfModule env_module>
    SetEnv MIBDIRS "D:/xampp/php/extras/mibs"
    SetEnv MYSQL_HOME "\\xampp\\mysql\\bin"
    SetEnv OPENSSL_CONF "D:/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.cnf"
    SetEnv PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR "\\xampp\\php"
    SetEnv PHPRC "\\xampp\\php"
    SetEnv TMP "\\xampp\\tmp"
</IfModule>

#
# PHP-Module setup
#
LoadFile "D:/xampp/php/php5ts.dll"
LoadFile "D:/xampp/php/libpq.dll"
LoadModule php5_module "D:/xampp/php/php5apache2_4.dll"

<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.phps$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
</FilesMatch>
```

[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzBIV.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztOM4.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwNuB.png)

I tried configuring the environment, checking the environment, configuring the virtual domain, but I got the error of not being able to start xampp

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iOM2LoOd2KQ